# Programmatically disable backup of the Documents directory in our App

Tags: objective-c, ios, icloud

We are creating folders and files in the Documents directory that can't be recreated, but it's a lot of data so we don't want these to be backed up in any way.

I know if we set this attribute "com.apple.mobilebackup" it will prevent iCloud backup, does it do the same when connecting to iTunes?

Comment: why not use the Cache directory?

Comment: If it can't be re-created Cache would be bad since the system can empty it.  On the other hand I would say if it really cannot be re-created, why on earth not let the system back it up?  What happens when the user gets a new phone or a replacement for a broken one?

Comment: "Programmatically"—do you mean at runtime or compile-time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, these files will be also ignored by the iTunes backup, as mentioned in the  [iOS Data Storage Guidelines.](https://developer.apple.com/icloud/documentation/data-storage/)